# Outlook Calendar ItemIds are different for Appointment Organizer and Appointment Attendee

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We are developing an Addin for Outlook Calendar using Office JS, such Addin being used by both Organizers and Attendees, using the same Taskpane JS code. We need thus to obtain a unique UID for the same appointment.

As documented,

- as Organizer using the `Office.AppointmentCompose` interface we use the method `getItemIdAsync`, i.e., `Office.context.mailbox.getItemIdAsync` and only after saving the Item for the ItemId to be available, and
- as Attendee using the `Office.AppointmentRead` interface we use the property `ItemId`, that is, `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId`

**But they are not the same!**

In the Addin JS code of the Attendee, how can I identify the ItemId of the Organizer of the appointment, in which the Attendee was invited for?

How can we have a common UID for Organizer and Attendee? Is there a EWS request I can make with `Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync`? Which XML request code then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appointment uid is exposed in both EWS (`UID` property) and in Graph (`uid` property). They will be the same for both the organizer and the attendee.

Comment: how to fetch UID in Office JS?

Comment: When you request for the appointment properties in EWS. UID will be included.

Comment: I used this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71589144/1243247

Comment: Do you see the UID node when you parse the XML response returned by your EWS request?

Comment: yes, it is working