# What is the EWS SOAP XML code to get ICalUid?

Tags: office-js, exchange-server, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

We're using Office JS to develop an Addin for Outlook Calendar. For the same appointment, the EWS Ids of the Organizer and Attendees [do not match](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2485#issuecomment-1072750807). Apparently I need `ICalUid` from Exchange which is common across organizer and attendees and common across different events for the same Item, exactly what we need. But Office JS does not provide such property nor method to fetch it ([only for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.icaluid?view=exchange-ews-api)).

But Office JS  provides [`Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) with which I can make SOAP requests to the Exchange server, using XML.

**What is the EWS SOAP XML code to get `ICalUid` from EWS Id?**

Does this work? Just replacing `FieldURI` with `ICalUid`?

```js
function getSubjectRequest(id) {
   // Return a GetItem operation request for the subject of the specified item. 
   var result = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
'               xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
'               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
'               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
'  <soap:Header>' +
'    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />' +
'  </soap:Header>' +
'  <soap:Body>' +
'    <GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">' +
'      <ItemShape>' +
'        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>' +
'        <t:AdditionalProperties>' +
'            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ICalUid"/>' +
'        </t:AdditionalProperties>' +
'      </ItemShape>' +
'      <ItemIds><t:ItemId Id="' + id + '"/></ItemIds>' +
'    </GetItem>' +
'  </soap:Body>' +
'</soap:Envelope>';

   return result;
}

function sendRequest() {
   // Create a local variable that contains the mailbox.
   var mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;

   mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(getSubjectRequest(mailbox.item.itemId), callback);
}

function callback(asyncResult)  {
   var result = asyncResult.value;
   var context = asyncResult.context;

   // Process the returned response here.
}
```

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/b71344ff-1581-4fc8-adda-681afe070255/getting-named-properties-via-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the IcalUid you would need

```
<t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:UID"/>
```

Keep in mind through the ICalUid isn't a searchable property so you won't be able to find Appointments based on this property if you need this then look at using the Extended Goid property like João linked in the comment.

Comment: Just to confirm: is `ICalUid` common (exactly the same) for both Organizer and all Attendees when I use respective EWS Ids as input?

Comment: what's the difference between `ICalUid` and Extended Goid property?

Comment: The Goid is an Exchange property that is used by Outlook to uniquely identify calendar appointments so will be the same on all instances see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxocal/1d3aac05-a7b9-45cc-a213-47f0a0a2c5c1.  It also get set on an invitations ,acceptances etc . ICalUid is a rfc property set on the Appointment see https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-4-7-unique-identifier.html

Comment: sorry, I understand nothing about soap requests to EWS, I am trying to develop a office js addin. Could you kindly post in your reply the full XML code to fetch the `ICalUid` from the ItemId? I did as you said (just replacing that line) and in the response I only get the ItemId again. What shall I put in the `BaseShape`? IdOnly?

Comment: just a final very relevant and important question for us: is `UID` (from the soap response, I guess it is ICalUid?) always the same over several instances? All the tests we made seemed that it is, but we wanted to be sure

Comment: Yes its the ICalUid

Comment: Thanks, thus UID is ICalUid. But it's always the same over several instances of a calendar event? Is it unique? Thanks again for your time

Comment: The iCalUid is unique for the appointment object (but not globally unique and as anything can set it not even guaranteed to be unique) , if its recurring the it will be same on each instance

Comment: in what cases the iCalUid changes? What do you mean by not globally unique?

Answer (score 0):

For the ones coming after me and for not losing *3 days* on this like I did, here is how I achieved

This function gets the ewsId for both Organizer and Attendee, since they have different means to get it

```js
// Event Outlook ID is available when
// a) Outlook event already existed in user's calendar or
// b) it was already saved by the user in the current session
function getEventOutlookUid (callback) {
  if (typeof Office.context.mailbox.item.getItemIdAsync === 'function') { // is Organizer
    Office.context.mailbox.item.getItemIdAsync(function (result) {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        callback(null, result.value)
      } else {
        console.warn(`EventOutlookUid unavailable: ${result.error.message}. Probably just a new event`)
        callback(null, null)
      }
    })
  } else if (Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId) { // is Attendee
    callback(null, Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId)
  } else {
    callback(Error('Neither Office.context.mailbox.item.getItemIdAsync nor Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId could get Outlook Item UID'))
  }
}
```

This function gets the extra IDs by parsing the XML from the SOAP request. You need jQuery since it is very easy to parse XML with it.

```js
function getExtendedIds (callback) {
  getEventOutlookUid((err, eventOutlookUid) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching Outlook UID ' + err.message)
      callback(Error(err))
    } else {
      const soapRequest = generateCalendarUidSoapRequest(eventOutlookUid)
      if (validateXML(soapRequest)) {
        Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(soapRequest, function (result) {
          if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            // console.log(prettifyXml(result.value))
            const res = $.parseXML(result.value)

            const changeKey = res.getElementsByTagName('t:ItemId')[0].getAttribute('ChangeKey')
            const UID = res.getElementsByTagName('t:UID')[0].textContent
            const GlobalObjectId = res.getElementsByTagName('t:GlobalObjectId')[0].textContent
            const ConversationId = res.getElementsByTagName('t:ConversationId')[0].getAttribute('Id')

            callback(null, { ewsId: eventOutlookUid, changeKey, UID, GlobalObjectId, ConversationId })
          }
        })
      } else {
        callback(Error('Invalid XML request'))
      }
    }
  })
}
```

This function generates the XML SOAP request to get all possible ids

```js
function generateCalendarUidSoapRequest (itemId) {
  const request = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
    '  <soap:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" /></soap:Header>' +
    '  <soap:Body>' +
    '    <m:GetItem>' +
    '      <m:ItemShape>' +
    '        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>' +
    '      </m:ItemShape >' +
    '      <t:AdditionalProperties>' +
    '        <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:UID"/>' +
    '        <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Meeting" PropertyId="3" PropertyType="Binary" />' +
    '      </t:AdditionalProperties>' +
    '      <m:ItemIds>' +
    '        <t:ItemId Id="' + itemId + '" />' +
    '      </m:ItemIds>' +
    '    </m:GetItem>' +
    '  </soap:Body>' +
    '</soap:Envelope>'

  return request
}
```

These are auxiliary functions to pretiffy and validate XML

```js
function prettifyXml (sourceXml) {
  const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(sourceXml, 'application/xml')
  const xsltDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString([
    // describes how we want to modify the XML - indent everything
    '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">',
    '  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>',
    '  <xsl:template match="para[content-style][not(text())]">', // change to just text() to strip space in text nodes
    '    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>',
    '  </xsl:template>',
    '  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">',
    '    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>',
    '  </xsl:template>',
    '  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>',
    '</xsl:stylesheet>'
  ].join('\n'), 'application/xml')

  const xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor()
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc)
  const resultDoc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlDoc)
  const resultXml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc)
  return resultXml
}

function validateXML (xmlString) {
  const domParser = new DOMParser()
  const dom = domParser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml')

  // print the name of the root element or error message
  return dom.documentElement.nodeName !== 'parsererror'
}
```

Just add all these functions to the scope/module, and then get the extra Ids by

```js
getExtendedIds((err, res) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(res)
  }
})
```

You'll have an object with `{ ewsId, changeKey, GlobalObjectId, ConversationId, UID }`